# Creating a new column that combines content of two other columns in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a `DataFrame` as follows:

[image]

I'd like to create a new `column` whose value is the 2nd and 3rd columns combined into a list in a cell.

i.e.

```
combined
[-8589.95, -6492.41]
[-1475.30, 249.52]
```

Any ideas how to do this? I get this error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

when I try to do something like this:

```
DF['combined'] = [DF['chicago_bound1'], DF['chicago_bound2']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df['combined'] = list(zip(df.chicago_bound1, df.chicago_bound2))
```

or

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: [[x.chicago_bound1, x.chicago_bound2]], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do selection by position by integer slices which you can out put to a list.

In this case your selection would be `df.iloc[0:2, 1:3]`

```
foo = df.iloc[0:2, 1:3].values.tolist()
df['combined']= foo
```

Output:

```
chicago     chicago_bound1  chicago_bound2  combined
0   -7541.18    -8589.95    -6492.41    [-8589.95, -6492.41]
1   -612.89     -1475.30    249.52  [-1475.3, 249.52]
```